# Matching non-string properties with Underscore.js's where

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is it possible in underscore to match items in a list based on a property that contains a nested object?

For example, using the popular `node-feedparser` on an MRSS feed will generate entries similar to this:

```
var item = {
    // a bunch of fields
    'ooyala:metadata': [
        {
            '@': {
                name: 'guid'
            },

            '#': 'a string'
        },
        {
            '@': {
                name: 'genre'
            },

            '#': 'music videos'
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a way to extract the GUID from a collection of items, so my first attempt was to simply:

```
var firstAttempt = _.where(item['ooyala:metadata'], { '@': { name: 'guid' } })
```

which returns an empty set.

Is there a way to get a member of a collection based on a nested object in underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter`, which takes a function as its second argument.

```
var correctWay = _.filter(item['ooyala:metadata'], function(item) {
    return item['@'].name === "guid";
});
```

I was trying to find a way to pass a function to `where` and didn't realize it was shorthand for a common use-case for `filter`.